# c++ read text file and store it to vector

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to read a textfile(item.txt) which is in this format 
itemId:itemDescription:itemCategory:itemSubCategory:amountPerUnit:itemQuantity:date
what I want is to read the textfile and store it inside a vector according to my expected output.

Comment: You should use a `struct` here. If you allow any modification to private members via public member functions, you might just as well make them all public.

Comment: @Jefffrey because I am more familiarize with java and just started learning c++, I tend to do things in a "java way of logic" but thanks for your suggestions I will read up on structs.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right way, by using `std::getline`. But instead you should read the file line by line, and then put the full line in an `std::istringstream`, and *then* you can use `std::getline` to tokenize the line.

You can't use the normal input operator `>>` as that separates on space.

---

Example

```
while (std::getline(readFile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string temp;

    std::getline(iss, temp, ':');
    itemId = std::stoi(temp);

    std::getline(iss, itemDescription, ':');
    std::getline(iss, itemCategory, ':');
    std::getline(iss, itemSubCategory, ':');

    std::getline(iss, temp, ':');
    amountPerUnit = std::stod(temp);

    std::getline(iss, temp, ':');
    quantity = std::stoi(temp);

    std::getline(iss, date, ':');

    // Create object and add it to the vector
}
```